# How can I improve my python script for parsing links?

Tags: python, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I wrote a test that parses links from a web page and in a loop clicks on each of them, and then returns to the main page. But each iteration is accompanied by parsing the entire web page again and again and overwriting the links array, Although only one link is needed per iteration. I understand that this is inefficient. How can I optimize this?

I tried parsing the links only once and then iterating through them in a loop. After the first iteration, it goes back (to the main page) and tries to click on the second link, but it's not interactive (I think it's because of the web elements that are stored in the links array changing every time you go to the page).

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver.get('https://yandex.ru')

def test_01(self): 
    driver = self.driver
    links = []
    time.sleep(3)
    links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
    for i in range(len(links)):
        links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
        links[i].click()
        driver.get('https://yandex.ru')
        time.sleep(3)
```

I expected more efficient solution.

Comment: If the code is working, you should ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: get links as strings and use `driver.get(link)` instead of `click`. And then you don't have to even go back to main page.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you navigate away from the page the [WebElements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) get invalidated as [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) changes therefore I would recommend going for [List Comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and convert the list of WebElements into the list of links text.
2. Once done you should be able to use [normalize-text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function just in case the text belongs to child element or has starting/trailing spaces
3. And last but not the least consider using [Explicit Wait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) just in case the link is populated via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) call.

Example code:

```
driver.get("http://yandex.ru")
links = [link.text for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")]
for link in links:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10) \
        .until(expected_conditions
        .presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//a[normalize-space()='" + link + "']"))).click()
    # do what you need here
    print(driver.title)
    driver.back()
driver.quit()
```